# Text only showing up in td element and not HTML

Tags: vue.js

I have a table td element that only shows this `&nbsp;` and I don't need it to appear like that but only as a blank space.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app2',
  beforeCreate: function() {

  },
  created: function() {

  },
  mounted: function() {},
  data: {
    itemPriceList: [],
    orderItems: [{
        globalGroupName: "-- ABC"
      },
      {
        globalGroupName: "-- CDE"
      },
      {
        globalGroupName: "--- FGH"
      },
      {
        globalGroupName: "- IJK"
      },
      {
        globalGroupName: "-- LMN"
      }
    ],
    priceList: null
  },
  methods: {
    GetOrderItems: function() {

    },
    ReplaceDashesInGlobalGroups: function(globalGroupName) {
      if (globalGroupName[0] === "-") {
        // Remove leading dashes and replace with a blank space
        console.log("ReplaceDashesInGlobalGroups");
        return globalGroupName.replace(/-(?![a-zA-Z])|-(?=\s|-)/g, '&nbsp;');
      }
      return globalGroupName;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app2">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" style="width:350px;">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th width="235px"><label>Global Name</label></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <template v-for="global in orderItems">
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ ReplaceDashesInGlobalGroups(global.globalGroupName) }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </template>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`<td v-html="ReplaceDashesInGlobalGroups(global.globalGroupName)"></td>`

This should be rendered as HTML now instead of just plain text. Note this can open you up to XSS attacks.

Source: [Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html)

> Updates the element’s innerHTML. **Note that the contents are inserted
> as plain HTML - they will not be compiled as Vue templates.** If you
> find yourself trying to compose templates using v-html, try to rethink
> the solution by using components instead.
>
> Dynamically rendering arbitrary HTML on your website can be very
> dangerous because it can easily lead to [XSS attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). Only use `v-html`
> on trusted content and **never** on user-provided content.
>
> In [single-file components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html), `scoped` styles will not apply to content
> inside `v-html`, because that HTML is not processed by Vue’s template
> compiler. If you want to target `v-html` content with scoped CSS, you
> can instead use CSS modules or an additional, global `<style>` element
> with a manual scoping strategy such as BEM.

Comment: That worked, and thanks for the link. I will accept as answer once I am able to

Comment: No worries, happy to help. I've added the documentation directly in to my answer to save you a click, or two!